# Does Loadrunner (VUGen) support Okta Authentication?

Tags: okta-api

Our application uses OKTA. We have to login to the OKTA portal,

I am used Web(HTTP/HTML).

[Does LoadRunner support the scripting and handling of applications that use Okta authentication as part of their login protocol? If so, can anyone point me to a guide/documentation that explains how this is handled?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz7SX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question asked on Micro Focus LoadRunner Professional community forum.

You can check for update [there](https://community.microfocus.com/t5/LoadRunner-Professional-User/Login-session-on-loadrunner/td-p/2865703).